# Can I create a factory to create servicesin AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I have this service I'd like to use, but it could happen that some parts of my application require the same service but with different parameters to use internally. Since services always refer to the same instance as far as I understand it, this would mean either manually having to edit the parameters everywhere before performing an action, or passing them in to every function. This would get messy very fast and I was wondering if it was possible to create a factory to initialise the different versions of the service I need.

Something like this, for instance:

```
function FooService(){
    this.setParams = function(params){
        ...
    }
};

function FooServiceFactory(){
    return{
        createService: function(name, params){
            var serv = new FooService();
            serv.setParams(params);
            ServiceModule.service(name, serv);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create factories as well.

```
app.factory("InstantiateMe", [function() {
    return function(params)
    {
        // some code
    };
}]);
app.controller("Ctrl", ["InstantiateMe", function(InstantiateMe) {
    var instance = new InstantiateMe({param: "value"});
}]);
```

In short, the factory function returns just that: a factory. Its return value can be an object, a function or, in this particular case, a constructor. You can this way instantiate multiple instances of your desired service.

Here is a [nice article on the subject](http://www.sitepoint.com/tidy-angular-controllers-factories-services/), elaborating on what I've summarised, that you may find useful.